# Dash Callback State of figure is dict instead of plotly.graph_objects.Figure()

Tags: python, graph, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have the following callback where I have the Graph as a State and Output. I'm expecting a `plotly.graph_objects.Figure()` from the parameter figure, but it is a `dict`.

```py
@app.callback(
        Output(f'graph1', 'figure'),
        [Input(f'interval1', 'n_intervals')],
        [State(f'graph1', 'figure')]
    )
    def update_graph_live(n_intervals, figure):
        # print(type(figure)) Output: <class 'dict'>
        # 
        # Following code does not work
        # my_figure = go.Figure(figure)
        # my_figure.update_traces(y=[1, 2, 3])
        # return my_figure

        # Following code works
        figure['data'][0]['y'] = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(3)]
        return figure
```

Even if I try to create a `go.Figure()` from it and then return it, it does nothing. Is there any explanation for this ?

The reason why I don't simply have a global fig variable is, because I'm generating multiple graphs. Here is a full example:

```py
import random
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash import Dash, Input, Output, State, dcc, html

employees = [{'name': 'John', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'Jane', 'age': 21}, {'name': 'Joe', 'age': 22}]

app = Dash(__name__) 

employee_cards = [] 
employee_id=0

for employee in employees:
    employee_id+=1

    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=[], name=f'Line{employee_id}'))

    employee_cards.append(html.Div([
        html.H3(employee['name']),
        html.P(employee['age']),
        dcc.Graph(
            id=f'graph{employee_id}',
            figure=fig
        ),
        dcc.Interval(
            id=f'interval{employee_id}',
            interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=0
        ),
    ]))

    
    @app.callback(
        Output(f'graph{employee_id}', 'figure'),
        [Input(f'interval{employee_id}', 'n_intervals')],
        [State(f'graph{employee_id}', 'figure')]
    )
    def update_graph_live(n_intervals, figure):
        # print(type(figure)) Output: <class 'dict'>
        # 
        # Following code does not work
        # my_figure = go.Figure(figure)
        # my_figure.update_traces(y=[1, 2, 3])
        # return my_figure

        # Following code works
        figure['data'][0]['y'] = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(3)]
        return figure

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Hello Dash'),
    html.Div(employee_cards)
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `dict` is the JSON serialized version of a `plotly.graph_objects.Figure()`:

> The figures created, manipulated and rendered by the plotly Python library are represented by tree-like data structures which are automatically serialized to JSON for rendering by the Plotly.js JavaScript library. These trees are composed of named nodes called "attributes", with their structure defined by the Plotly.js figure schema, which is available in machine-readable form. The plotly.graph_objects module (typically imported as go) contains an automatically-generated hierarchy of Python classes which represent non-leaf nodes in this figure schema. The term "graph objects" refers to instances of these classes.

https://plotly.com/python/graph-objects/

I think the code you commented out does work, but the data you pass doesn't change so you don't see the figure change. The other example you gives passes random data to the figure so you do see the figure change.

Modified version of your first approach inside your callback using data from your second approach:

```
my_figure = go.Figure(figure)
my_figure.update_traces(y=[random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(3)])
return my_figure
```